# How to create LIKE operator search in Redis cache using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a question, is it possible to create a `LIKE` operator search in Redis? Similar to relational (mysql/oracle) database.

I have complex json:

```
   {"_id" : ObjectId("581c8b8854fdcd1ff8c944e0"),
"Objectcode" : "xxxxx",
"Objecttype" : "xxxx",
"docid" : "581c8b8554fdcd1ff8c93d10",
"description" : "Tags based search .... ",
"metaTags" : [ 
    "tag1", 
    "tag2", 
    "tag3", 
    "tag5", 
    "tag6", 
    "tag7", 
    "tag8", 
    "tag9", 
    "tag10"
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

and i want to search on array of metaTags how can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redis ***SCAN** commands http://redis.io/commands/scan, depending of your [*type of data*](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) to filter by a pattern:

> - [**SCAN**](http://redis.io/commands/scan) iterates the set of keys in the currently selected Redis database.
> - [**SSCAN**](http://redis.io/commands/sscan) iterates elements of *Sets* types.
> - [**HSCAN**](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) iterates fields of Hash types and their associated values.
> - [**ZSCAN**](http://redis.io/commands/zscan) iterates elements of Sorted Set types and their associated scores.

Never use **KEYS** in app code, because it may ruin performance.

The two major nodejs redis client libraries *node_redis* and *ioredis* support it, with some syntax sugar:

```
const keys = [];
const redis = new Redis(); // ioredis
redis.mset('foo1', 1, 'foo2', 1, 'foo3', 1, 'foo4', 1, 'foo10', 1, () => {
  const stream = redis.scanStream();
  stream.on('data', data => {
    keys = keys.concat(data);
  });
  stream.on('end', () => {
    assert.equal(keys.sort(), ['foo1', 'foo10', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4']);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have before to transform iand denormalize it to redis data-types: http://redis.io/topics/data-types focusing on how you expect to query it

Comment: thanks, I am using npm redis not ioredis. above link is very normal JSON but I am looking for complex JSON Search. thanks you somuch.

Comment: Redis is a key-value database (often used as LRU cache), not a document store. It doesn't work with JSON types, so you have to transform it in hashes/sets/lists and other redis data-types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATCH   commands to search data.

```
Eg: scan 0 MATCH *11*
```

Refer: http://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: thanks, I was tried above link but there is no luck,  before this question post.