# Yii2 redis search analogy of mysql "LIKE"

Tags: mysql, redis, datatables, yii2

I'm building a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with yii2 backend, that outputs result from redis inside table. I have 4 columns in which the search should be performed. But i don't know how to search in redis similraly to mysql `LIKE`:

Currently i have the following code inside my controller action, which meant to ouput js to the  datatable:

```
if(!empty($global_search["value"]))
            foreach($columns as $column){
                $condition[$column["name"]] = $global_search["value"].'*';
            }

$output = $stat->find()->where($condition);
```

This result in the following `$condition`:

```
$condition = {array} [5]
 id = "100"
 Ip = "W*"
 Hits = "W*"
 User-Agent = "W*"
 OS = "W*"
```

Id is current user id, for which stats are stored, the rest of the columns, tried to be searched by `W*` i assume it will find all the records, where any columns have `W<any characters>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean the JQuery plug-in datatables? https://datatables.net/

Comment: @vahdet yes, this one

Comment: @vahdet i use server side processing, whenever user inputs some search value, inside datatables widget, i need to do the query inside redis, but i'm not sure how to search in redis, as there is no `like` operator like in  mysql

Comment: If the real question is only about **searching in redis**, this question can be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40761383/4636715

Comment: @vahdet this is using raw query. But can i do this from the yii2 wrapper? `where`?